# Struts2 IllegalArgumentException exception handling?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, struts2, illegalargumentexception

I have a Stateless Session Bean:

```
public CmcMapServerInfo getMapServerDetails() throws IllegalArgumentException, PersistenceException{

        Query query;
        List<CmcMapServerInfo> resultList;
        CmcMapServerInfo mapServer = null;

        try{
            query = em.createNamedQuery("CmcMapServerInfo.getMapServerr");
            resultList = query.getResultList();
            mapServer =  resultList.get(0); // as only single row is there
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println(" ILLEGAL CATCHED------------------------------------------------------------");
            throw e;
        }catch(PersistenceException e){
            System.out.println(" PERSISTENCE CATCHED------------------------------------------------------------");
            throw e;
        }
        return mapServer;
    }
```

Here `CmcMapServerInfo.getMapServerr` is illegal argument, thus an `IllegalArgumentException` is catched here and rethrown to the `Action class` where the this function was called.

**Action class:**

```
public String getMapServerDetails(){

        try{
            mapServer = getSlsConfigureMapServerRemote().getMapServerDetails();
        }catch(NamingException e){
            System.out.println("NAMING EXCEPTION INSIDE :---------------");
            addActionError("There was an Error displaying the Required Page. Please Contact the system Adminstrator");
            return ERROR;
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("ILLEGAl ARG INSIDE :---------------");
            addActionError("There was an Error getting the Map Server Details. Please Contact the system Adminstrator");
            return ERROR;
        }catch(PersistenceException e){
            System.out.println("PERSISTENCE INSIDE :---------------");
            addActionError("There was an Error getting the Map Server Details. Please Contact the system Adminstrator");
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

The problem is here inside the `Action class` the rethrown exception from bean is not caught, thus struts2 exception Interceptor handles it.

I have configured struts2 exception handling in my **struts.xml**:

```
<package name="cdot.oss.cmsat.conf.mapserver.struts" namespace="/"
        extends="struts-default">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="appDefaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
                    <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
                    <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="appDefaultStack" />

        <global-results>
            <result name="exception">mapServer/pages/Exception.jsp</result>
        </global-results>

        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception"
                result="exception" />
        </global-exception-mappings>


        <action name="getMapServerDetails"
            class="cdot.oss.cmsat.conf.struts.ConfigureMapServerAction" method="getMapServerDetails">

            <result name="success">mapServer/pages/ConfigureMapServerInput.jsp
            </result>
            <result name="input">mapServer/pages/ConfigureMapServerInput.jsp
            </result>
            <result name="error">mapServer/pages/Error.jsp</result>


        </action>
```

Since exception is not caught inside Action class, the `global exception mapping` of `Exception` handles it and displays the `Exception.jsp`.

Why is the exception not catched in `Action class` even though it's catched in Bean and rethrown there?

Comment: If catch Throwable at the end of your try, does the exception appears there?

Comment: @ThrashBean: Throwable in Action class or Bean?

Comment: @ThrashBean: If I write throwable block inside action class at the end, it reaches inside throwable. I did a sysout inside throwable

Comment: @Siddhartha, thats just to know if the exception is raised to the action class, nothing more. Well, probably IllegalArgumentException is  wrapped in other type of exception. Please do this - catch Throwable and inside the block check the cause. Debugging must be easy with a breakpoint on the system.out. You should know how the exception is wrapped.

Comment: @ThrashBean: CAUSE----------java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: CmcMapServerInfo.getMapServerr not found.

Comment: Well, you catched it. Is not very elegant but check "if (e.getCause() instanceof java.lang.IllegalArgumentException){...}" and do what you need. Why the exception is not caught in the own catch block? No idea. It should be, but it isn't... Hope that helped you.